# optimization with non linear constraints ("semi-continuous")

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

## Program

The problem can be written as:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:maxProgGeneral}
    \max_{r = (r_1,\ldots,r_n) \in \mathcal{P}_N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \varphi_i(r_i)
\end{equation}
where *φ*<sub>*i*</sub>(*r*) are concave and "nice", with
*φ*<sub>*i*</sub>′(*r*) continous but *φ*<sub>*i*</sub>″(*r*) is not (it
has a jump). Out of curiosity here are what they might look like.
*φ*<sub>*i*</sub>(*r*) is in Figure 1 and *φ*<sub>*i*</sub>″(*r*) is in Figure 2.

[*φ*<sub>*i*</sub>  Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT946.png)

and *φ*<sub>*i*</sub>′(*r*) looks like as follows. As you can see there
is a jump in *φ*<sub>*i*</sub>″(*r*) at 0.

[*φ*<sub>*i*</sub> ′ Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI06N.png)

### Constraint space <sub>*N*</sub>

The optimzation space <sub>*N*</sub> has the following primary
conditions:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^N r_i = 1$
2. *r*<sub>*i*</sub> ≥ 0
3. *r*<sub>*i*</sub> CAN take the value 0, so a solution on the
   boundary is acceptable (even encouraged in some cases).

#### Additional constaints

I can solve the problem above wihtout an issue. Now I would like to add
the following. I have ∀*i* minimums *m*<sub>*i*</sub> ≥ 0 such that ∃
*i* with *m*<sub>*i*</sub> = 0.

The next set of optimizations are:

1. ∀*i*, *r*<sub>*i*</sub> ≥ *m*<sub>*i*</sub> OR *r*<sub>*i*</sub> = 0

This means that if *r*<sub>*i*</sub> has a non 0 allocation, then it has
to be above *m*<sub>*i*</sub>.

**Note:** I assumed ∃ *i* with *m*<sub>*i*</sub> = 0 in order to
guarantee the existance of a solution that is compatible with the first
condition $\sum_{i=1}^N r_i = 1$. Otherwise I don't really need it I
am ok with getting no solution.

## Questions

1. What are such problems called
2. What references are there that address these problem
3. What libraries are there to solve this (anything in R?)

## Thank you for your help

## Update (see answer below)

1. These are called "semi-continuous" constraints
2. Fall under the MIP/MINLP models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing what is called "**semi-continuous**" variables. Many MIP (and some MINLP) solvers support them directly, but they can also be formulated using binary variables:

Let $r_i \in \{0\} \cup [m_i,u_i]$ (i.e. zero or between $m_i$ and $u_i$). Then:

$$
\delta_i m_i \le r_i \le \delta_i u_i
$$

where $\delta_i\in \{0,1\}$ is a binary decision variable, will give you a semi-continuous behavior.

As an example. semi-continuous variables are used in portfolio models where we want to prevent very small positions.

Anyway, you are now in the realm of MINLP modeling.

Note: MIP means (linear) Mixed Integer Programming, and MINLP means Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good direction. A quick search found the parma package in R https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parma/index.html which as you mentionned is for portfolio optimization.